# unknown attribute: queue with delayed_job after update of rails 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, delayed-job

All in the title.
After the security warning, I updated my rails 3.2.3 to 3.2.11
Every things ok but I realize that the delayed job doesn't send messages anymore with the error "unknown attribute: queue"

I tried to recreate the update migration : rails generate delayed_job:upgrade
But it tell me that already exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `rake db:migrate`

`rails generate delayed_job:upgrade` generated a migration but your database doesn't get modified until you actually run the migration.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Alternate to @brettish's answer, you can do it by yourself (I am writing this because, I ran into same issue and `delayed_job:upgrade` generator was undefined for me).

In version 3, `queue` attribute is added.

You can follow these steps:

Create migration
`rails generate migration AddQueueToDelayedJobs`

Add `queue` to delayed_jobs table as follows:

```
class AddQueueToDelayedJobs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def self.up
    add_column :delayed_jobs, :queue, :string
  end
  def self.down
    remove_column :delayed_jobs, :queue
  end
end
```

Note: I am using rails 5.1.

Hope it helps!